# Magento 2.4.2-p2 change "Select From Gallery" root folder

Tags: magento2, media-images, gallery

Good afternoon all,

I am working on a site that has large amount of images (110k +) in the media folders. The media select screen opens and sits loading from storage root but I would like to set the root folder to be the wyswiwyg folder. This would allow our content editors access the gallery with out having to wait 10-15mins for it to load every time as there are only about 8k worth of images there. I will be looking at a large scale clear out but the pressing issue is access to the wyswiwyg folder.

I am also open to other options for dealing large scale Magento 2 media folders. I have inherited the issue and would like to find a way to improve the admin experience.

Any help would be very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while but I wanted to add a short update on this issue.

The solution required a change of work flow for our editor teams, an upgrade for M2 to 2.4.5, enabling of the new gallery type as well as quite a lot of leg work in cleaning up and organising the media (on going process).

We now have a gallery that loads in about 15 -20 secs, a vast improvement on the 15 mins.

There were no shortcuts, required a honest review of the process and a large scale cleanup.